# Different kinds of clicks in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouse, core-foundation

I have just bought a Wacom Bamboo touch tablet. It works fine with all applications except the Twitter client, which gets a bit confused when I click on a link.

Is there a quick bit of code I can knock up / API I can call to see what kind of mouse events are being generated by the driver (just to satisfy my curiosity)?

To clarify: I'm not writing an app here... just trying to use a product and work out why it's not working properly.

Comment: Might be best to post your mouse event handling code to save the inevitable round of back-and-forth questioning. :-)

Comment: I'll clarify. I'm only a user here, I'm using the stock Twitter client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tablet events](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventObjectsTypes/EventObjectsTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH4-SW3) are somewhat different than mouse events. Specifically:

> A [tablet] pointer event is an NSEvent object of type NSTabletPoint or
>   an object representing a mouse-down, mouse-dragged, or mouse-up event
>   with a subtype of NSTabletPointEventSubtype.

Comment: Interesting. I assumed that the Wacom driver would just fake standard mouse events. I would have thought it's no different to Magic Trackpad, in principle.

Comment: It's a trackpad, not a tablet (no pressure sensitivity etc).

Comment: Sorry, no. You mentioned a Wacom Bamboo, which *is* considered a tablet device and is handled differently. Even if your model doesn't support pressure sensitivity, pen-based input on a digitizing tablet is handled differently in Cocoa.

Comment: Ah okay. The Bamboo line has both pen-based input and touch based input (two sensors in one package). I assumed that it would behave as two separate devices. (That said, I have the touch-only version).

Comment: It's possible assumptions are being made about the device by its type in some custom view code in the Twitter app. Without the code, it's hard to tell what's going on. Touch-based devices might also have drivers that are doing ... unsupported things to possibly support multitouch. There are just too many variables.